# using the GPU power in javascript

Tags: javascript, gpu, blockchain

I'm looking for a way to use the GPU computing power inside my NodeJS or Javascript App. DApp actually.

The code is javascript and very basic.

```
generateHash(block) {

     let hash = sha256(block.key)        

     while(!hash.startsWith("0000")) {   
       block.nonce += 1                 
       hash = sha256(block.key)                  
       console.log(hash)             
     }

     return hash

   }
```

So how could I use the GPU to hash by blocks in this case?

Comment: look onto gpu.js and turbo.js

Comment: https://github.com/kashif/node-cuda

Comment: Node-cuda is good for nvidia card so il keep that ine mind. Im still looking at how i could use gpujs. to perform some hash. will try to update the post soon. working on it

Comment: I believe you'll find that both gpu.js and tensorflow.js are somewhat limited in their logical operations (ie, AND, OR, XOR, etc) on integers.  For example, the [tf.logicalAnd](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#logicalAnd) operates on a tensor element of true/false rather than a binary integer.  And the [gpu.js math functions](https://github.com/gpujs/gpu.js/#supported-math-functions) lack logicals.  This makes calculating SHA256 via Javascript/GPU somewhat challenging to say the least...